# ASP.NET treeview manipulation api for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, treeview

In my asp.net solution, I have a asp.net tree view, and I want to make some client side manipulations to it. I am basically looking for a way in jQuery, to do

- iterate through all root nodes
- iterate through all sub nodes given a node
- get the text of the given node
- get the value of the given node
- add a blue highlight around the text of the given node
- expand/collapse given node

I don't want to use any other kind of jQuery tree view plugins either. Does anyone know if there is a project that someone did to do this? Or can provide links or code to do this?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT** :

Here is an example of the HTML structure:

[image]

```
<DIV id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview>
    <TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn0 href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data,0,ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn0,' ',ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn0Nodes)"><IMG style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" alt="Collapse 1. A" src="/WebResource.axd?d=oKkfR-BHb97Y7tPLeoIZ5CuPUYp5n51Q4XEiQRUTaq1HISixWa68nxn2YUcnu0P4F-QpKQAcYmkDFOY--39rPe3LvzCxPUlUASBT63y5J9TTXtUk0&amp;t=634605054607203927"></A></TD>
                <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" class=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_2><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt0 class="ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_0 ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_1" onclick="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data,0,ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn0,' ',ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn0Nodes)" href="javascript:void(0);" target=_self>1. A</A></TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: block" id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn0Nodes>
        <TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <DIV style="WIDTH: 20px; HEIGHT: 1px"></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD><IMG alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=wVUEBOQcgjQn-5A_RWLY_fRfV16DlyE_TEShuFyVd0dtheEKaRWia9U8hMe7BvBalON1Kc8T7hXyEcYAYP1zafcbfrHc3IQbxc_merS67hdm_-KX0&amp;t=634605054607203927"></TD>
                    <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap"><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt1 class=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_0 onclick="javascript:TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data, this,'ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt1');" href='javascript:DisplayPDF("ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_pdf_and_searchResults_container","http://mydomain/mylibrary/1. A/5.5 Quick Reference Guide.pdf","850","1100", null);' target=_self>1. 5.5 Quick Reference Guide</A></TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        <TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <DIV style="WIDTH: 20px; HEIGHT: 1px"></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD><IMG alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=wVUEBOQcgjQn-5A_RWLY_fRfV16DlyE_TEShuFyVd0dtheEKaRWia9U8hMe7BvBalON1Kc8T7hXyEcYAYP1zafcbfrHc3IQbxc_merS67hdm_-KX0&amp;t=634605054607203927"></TD>
                    <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap"><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt2 class=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_0 onclick="javascript:TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data, this,'ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt2');" href='javascript:DisplayPDF("ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_pdf_and_searchResults_container","http://mydomain/mylibrary/1. A/5.6 Upgrade.pdf","850","1100", null);' target=_self>2. 5.6 Upgrade</A></TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
    </DIV>
    <TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn3 href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data,3,ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn3,' ',ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn3Nodes)"><IMG style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" alt="Collapse 2. B" src="/WebResource.axd?d=oKkfR-BHb97Y7tPLeoIZ5CuPUYp5n51Q4XEiQRUTaq1HISixWa68nxn2YUcnu0P4F-QpKQAcYmkDFOY--39rPe3LvzCxPUlUASBT63y5J9TTXtUk0&amp;t=634605054607203927"></A></TD>
                <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" class=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_2><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt3 class="ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_0 ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_1" onclick="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data,3,ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn3,' ',ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn3Nodes)" href="javascript:void(0);" target=_self>2. B</A></TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: block" id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn3Nodes>
        <TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <DIV style="WIDTH: 20px; HEIGHT: 1px"></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD><IMG alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=wVUEBOQcgjQn-5A_RWLY_fRfV16DlyE_TEShuFyVd0dtheEKaRWia9U8hMe7BvBalON1Kc8T7hXyEcYAYP1zafcbfrHc3IQbxc_merS67hdm_-KX0&amp;t=634605054607203927"></TD>
                    <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap"><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt4 class=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_0 onclick="javascript:TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data, this,'ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt4');" href='javascript:DisplayPDF("ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_pdf_and_searchResults_container","http://mydomain/mylibrary/2. B/8830 Downloading PodCasts.pdf","850","1100", null);' target=_self>1. 8830 Downloading PodCasts</A></TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
    </DIV>
    <TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
        <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn5 href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data,5,ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn5,' ',ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn5Nodes)"><IMG style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" alt="Collapse 3. C" src="/WebResource.axd?d=oKkfR-BHb97Y7tPLeoIZ5CuPUYp5n51Q4XEiQRUTaq1HISixWa68nxn2YUcnu0P4F-QpKQAcYmkDFOY--39rPe3LvzCxPUlUASBT63y5J9TTXtUk0&amp;t=634605054607203927"></A></TD>
                <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" class=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_2><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt5 class="ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_0 ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_1" onclick="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data,5,ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn5,' ',ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn5Nodes)" href="javascript:void(0);" target=_self>3. C</A></TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: block" id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewn5Nodes>
        <TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                        <DIV style="WIDTH: 20px; HEIGHT: 1px"></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD><IMG alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=wVUEBOQcgjQn-5A_RWLY_fRfV16DlyE_TEShuFyVd0dtheEKaRWia9U8hMe7BvBalON1Kc8T7hXyEcYAYP1zafcbfrHc3IQbxc_merS67hdm_-KX0&amp;t=634605054607203927"></TD>
                    <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap"><A id=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt6 class=ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_0 onclick="javascript:TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeview_Data, this,'ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_my_treeviewt6');" href='javascript:DisplayPDF("ctl00_m_g_7276d5bd_969d_40e4_b299_08b2f89c43e9_ctl00_pdf_and_searchResults_container","http://mydomain/mylibrary/3. C/8830 International Roaming.pdf","850","1100", null);' target=_self>1. 8830 International Roaming</A></TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: I dont know of any links, but if you get started trying, at leasting show us the HTML as is after page load, I'm sure one of us could start you on the right path to writing the jQuery. None of you're requirments are hard, but without a real idea of how the "treeview" lays as HTML, there's not much I can tell you on how to write the code.

Comment: ok I added some code here.

Comment: I know my answer might not be exactly what you're looking for. But it sounded in your question, as if you were looking to "know" how to do these types of things "by hand". Thus I tried to give you plenty of example on how to use jQuery to do all the different things you might need to do to accomplish each task. From there, you can determine what methods to apply and where, I hope. If you need more information on something, just comment on my answer so I get a notice and i'll stop back by and update what I can. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, as i mentioned, I don't know of any links. That HTML was a little tuff, ASP default design I'm assuming. Been a while since I worked with ASP. Any who. I made an example fiddle with a lot of comment in "per item demand" detail based on your question. I give a small example of how to perform each task separately along with some other useful information. For more information, be sure to frequently check http://api.jquery.com/

## Examples

```
//  the following will get the main tree view wrapper, unless you change your ID names of course
//  by useing `.not('[id*=Nodes]')`, we can eliminate all div's having "my_treeview" without elementating the parent
//  you could also use `.first()` and get the same result
//  simply showing a couple different ways jQuery offers "selection" of elements
var treeView = $('div[id*=my_treeview]').not('[id*=Nodes]');
clog(treeView, 'Tree View Element');

//  ***  iterate through all root nodes  ***
treeView.children('table').each(function(i) { // `i` = index number (0 based)
    var node = $(this),  //  get current node
        nodeSub = $(this).next("div");  //  get sub nodes if avaialbe, if not, this will be empty jQuery Object
    clog([node, nodeSub], 'Node && Sub');
})

//  ***  iterate through all sub nodes given a node  ***
var given = treeView.children('table').first(); // in this case, just grabs first node, since it has multiple subs
clog(given, 'Given Sub Node');
given.next('div').children('table').each(function(i) {
    var subNode = $(this);
    clog(subNode, 'Sub Nodes of First Node');
});

//  ***  get the text of the given node  ***
//  this selector based on given HTML example of all node text being in an A tag having an
//  ID that contains the phrase `my_treeviewt`
//  i would suggest using class names like ('node-text') instead
treeView.find('a[id*=my_treeviewt]').each(function(i) {
    clog($(this).text(), 'Node Text by Each Node && Sub Node'); 
});

//  ***  get the value of the given node  ***
//  ??? UNSURE of your intent with this one ???

//  ***  add a blue highlight around the text of the given node  ***
given.find("a").last().css({ 'background-color': '#2AF', 'color': '#FFA' })
//  here i change the css of an element by hand using traditional CSS names
//  jQuery does include some shortcut options, my suggestiong would be to make a 'highglight' class,
//  then simply use `addClass('highlight')` or `removeClass('highligh')`


//  ***  expand/collapse given node  ***
//  selector based on layout, but again, I would suggest setting up class names to use like
//  `.node` and/or '.node.sub-node'
$('div > table a').attr('onclick', ''); // first i remove all the set onclicks for now, they cause their own interference
$(document).on('click', 'div > table a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //  stop href link from working on an A tag
    var parent = $(this).closest('table');  //  finds first parent table, aka, the "node"
    if (parent.next('div').length) {    //  will return false if there is not a sub node
        var sub = parent.next('div');
        if (sub.is(':visible')) {   //  note, this does not just check 'visible' css state, it also checks if 'display' css is set or if it is 'none'
            sub.hide();
        }
        else {
            sub.show();
        }
    }
})
```